# React can't load jpg image when redirected to home page when loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, webpack, react-router

I have a react app that redirects the user to the home page on start. If I use `<Redirect to="/Home">` I am taken to the page, but my image is not loaded and I am met with a **404 error**. However, if I don't use redirect and just load the  component at the start in my render function, the image appears just fine and there are no issues with pathing. Something odd occurs when using Redirect and I am not sure if I am using the correct approach for setting up a default page for when the app starts.

The image is within my src folder under src/media/profile.jpg. Whether I add a "./" in front of the path or remove the forward slash, the results are the same. I've done import statements for the image and even tried `src={require('../media/profile.jpg')}` in the image tag. The issue is only when I redirect.

**With Redirect**

[image]

**Render Function from App class**

`

```
  <Router>
  <Redirect from="/" to="/Home" />
  
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/Home">
        <Home />
    </Route>
    <Route exact path="/ReactDefault">
        <ReactDefault />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
  </Router>
    
    
  </main>
```

**Import in homepage**

`import  Avatar  from '../media/profile.jpg'`

`//var Avatar = require('../media/profile.jpg')`

**Home Page**

`

```
  <Router>
  <img  src={Avatar}  id="avatar" alt="avatar"></img>
  <div id="cardup-wrap">
    <card-up><Link id="test" to="/ReactDefault" ><h2 >Test1</h2></Link></card-up>
    <card-up><Link id="test" to="/ReactDefault" ><h2>Test1</h2></Link></card-up>
    <card-up><Link id="test" to="/ReactDefault" ><h2>Test1</h2></Link></card-up>
  </div>

  </Router>

</div>`
```

`
{

**Webpack Config**

`test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,`

```
    use: [

      {
        loader: 'file-loader',

      },
    ],
  }`
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be easilly solved by putting that image inside of public folder and then referencing it like so: `src="/{Your-Image.jpg}"`.

Comment: The forward slash outside of the curly braces causes a syntax error. I think its supposed to be `src={"/"+Your-Image.jpg}` from what I have seen online. Yet even then, I moved the image to the same level as my App script and the results were the same.

Comment: Ok, now, move your image inside of the /public folder. Let's say your image name is "Kyle.jpg". Go ahead and write `src="/Kyle.jpg"`

Comment: Im just met with `Cannot GET /profile.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

I got the image to load while using the `<Redirect>` tag. I am not sure why, but the issue was resolved when I switched my loader in my webpack config file from `file-loader` to `url-loader`. After making that switch, the app works appropriately. However, I don't really know what the true problem was :/